# How to acceleration animation when its about to end

Tags: java, android, animation

Here is my code

```
final ObjectAnimator transAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "y", image.getY(), 20);
                        transAnimation.setDuration(duration);
                        transAnimation.start();
```

Right now the animation slows down when animation about to complete. I want it to accelerate instead. Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android provides a bunch of ready-made Interpolators. The one you're looking for is most-likely the Accelerate Interpolator : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AccelerateInterpolator.html

To have your animation play with it, simply change your code to :

```
final ObjectAnimator transAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(image, "y", image.getY(), 20);
                    transAnimation.setDuration(duration);
                    transAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                    transAnimation.start();
```